# Stop automatic sort of column 1

Tags: google-sheets

So lets say I have sheet1

```
a | 4
b | 5
c | 33
d | 55
```

and sheet2

```
a | 1
b | 2
c | 3
e | 2
```

And using this query

```
=query({Sheet1!A1:B10;Sheet2!A1:B10},"select Col1, Avg(Col2), count(Col1) where Col1 is not NULL group by Col1 label Col1 'name', count(Col1) 'number of times referenced?', Avg(Col2) 'average'")
```

I get sheet 3 below

```
name | average | number of times referenced?
a         2.5              2
b         3.5              2 
c         18               2  
d         55               1
e         2                1
```

The problem is it is automatically sorted by the name column, but I would like to be able to sort by all 3 columns if possible.

an example if I decided to sort by average it would look like

```
name | average | number of times referenced?
d        55              2
c        18              2 
b        3.5             2  
a        2.5             1
e        2               1
```

Comment: I mean being able to sort by each of the 3 columns one at a time. So I could sort by average on its own, name on its own and number of times referenced on its own. But at the moment when I try to sort Average or number of times column1 just auto sorts again

Comment: I've updated the example showing what I mean by sorting by average

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either adapt the QUERY to sort according to the desired column (and then again for a different choice), for example to sort on `average` descending insert

```
 order by Avg(Col2) desc
```

before `label`, or:

Select/Copy/Paste special/Paste values only and then apply the standard sheet sorting.

Comment: I guess that's what I'll have to do